# Division ring and Quadratic Extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, division-ring

First We define involution map which is map

$*$ : $R \rightarrow R$ such that it satisfy

$ i)\ (a+b)^* = a^*+ b^*$  $ii)\ (ab)^* = b^*a^*$ $iii) (a^*)^* = a$

for $a,b$ in $R$.

Now $Z$ be center of ring $R$   now define Involution of first kind over $R$  where $R$ is division  ring such that [image]

How to describe involution of second kind and what is the automorphism of order 2 here? Also I know that $Z/Z_0$ is galois quadratic extension but why it is quadratic and what is minimal polynomial associated with it?
[image]

Comment: Let $G=\{Id,{}^*\}$. If $a\in Z, a \not \in Z_0$ then  $(X-a)(X-a^*)  = X^2 -(a+a^*)X +aa^*\in Z^G[X]=Z_0[X]$ is its $Z_0$-minimal polynomial so $Gal(Z/Z_0) = G$ and $[Z:Z_0]=2$. Do you have an example of such division ring ? (in the quaternions $Z = Z_0 = \mathbb{R}$)

Comment: @reuns why polynomial in $Z_0[X]$?

Comment: Is this an example : the $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$ quaternions $u+vj, (u,v) \in K^2, j^2 = -1, vj = j \overline{v}$, look at the usual quaternion involution $\rho(u+vj) = \overline{u}-j\overline{v}$ then compose it with $\sigma \in Gal(K/\mathbb{Q}(i)), \sigma(\sqrt{2}) =-\sqrt{2}$ that is $(u+vj)^* = \rho(\sigma(u)+\sigma(v)j)$. 
It should work because $\rho$ is an involution of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$-algebra.

Comment: @reuns are you there?